# How to get value from xml element using Linq to xml concept in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-xml

```
XElement MyFamily = new XElement("MyFamily",
                                new XElement("Parents",
                                    new XElement("Father", "Anjappan",
                                        new XAttribute("Id", "AA1234")),
                                    new XElement("Mother", "Thaiyamuthu",
                                        new XAttribute("Id", "AA4567"))),
                                new XElement("Brothers", "Senthil,Saravanan,Sathish"),
                                new XElement("Systers", "Povunamma,Pazhaniyamma,Sangeetha"));
        MyFamily.Save(@System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MyFamily_RemoveElement.xml");
```

Here i want to get **father** value("Anjappan") and **Id** value("AA12345") using Linq to xml concept. what should i do for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 var element = MyFamily.Descendants("Father")
                  .Where(
                   p => p.Value == "Anjappan" 
                   && p.Attribute("Id").Value == "AA1234"
                   ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) to get node, [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute.aspx) to get attribute, and [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) to get the element/node value.

```
    var fatherNode  = MyFamily.Descendants("Father"); //Father Nodes
    var fatherId = fatherNode.Attributes("Id").First().Value; // "AA1234")
    var farthName = fatherNode.First().Value; //"Anjappan"
```